# Full screen game not running in full screen, under wine?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I can't seem to play Grim Dawn (only game I'm currently playing) **in full screen**: even though it's in full screen selected inside the game, it's in a window. It's problem because it cuts part of the image: from both bottom as well as right side.

Here's a screenshot with the problem:

[image]

as can be seen, it cuts part of the bottom as well as a sizeable chunk from the right size.

Here's a pic taken from the net of this screen,

[image]

so that you can see how much is being cut off.

The workaround is to select the 2nd highest resolution. it works because I can see the whole picture but that's because, even though it's supposed to be in full screen, it's actually on a window. That's not full screen at all.

**I have less then 2 months experience using Linux and I chose Ubuntu 16.04**. please keep that in mind when posting solutions to this problem because I may not know how to implement them.

Comment: what command to you use to launch the game? how do you configure the wine prefixes  the issue is that Wine needs to be told not to use a virtual desktop

Comment: I  followed the guide from http://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/grim-dawn-guide.1032/: i just click on the shortcut it leaves on the desktop to start the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is why the game is in a window:

[image]

If play-on-linux allows it. open the wine configuration for the prefix where the game is installed and uncheck `Emulate a virtual desktop`

Note: if this is a steam game, Steam has a linux version.

Comment: I thought i had that disabled. Turns out i had disabled another winecfg. Went to PlayonLinux and checked wine configuration and ... it was enabled ... DUH ...

Comment: Setting this option has no effect when set in Lutris.

Comment: @Ravery can you please say where is this configuration?

Comment: I did not find it in my Programs GUI , but from the terminal you can open it with `winecfg` or `winecfg-development` :)

Answer (score -1):

I really thought i had tried this before (ravery's fix), as can be seen in this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQKM0.jpg).

Turns out it was the wrong winecfg, which is why it didn't work.

Just tried it via PlayonLinux instead of from the terminal and finally **FINALLY** i get to play the game in full screen!!!

This problem seems solved!

Comment: Since you are new to the site: since ravery solved your problem, you should click the checkmark beside his answer to indicate that it's correct. Upvoting it would also be nice. It's def not cool to post another answer yourself taking credit for what someone else told you.

Comment: I'm sorry: not my intention. I had checked the "this answer is useful" from @ravery 's post since that is the cause of this solution. Also accepted his answer just now, which is what i hadn't done before.